# Getting error in latitude and longitude in react

Tags: reactjs, json

When I try to get the latitude and longitude from the JSON it is showing the error.

Error:

```
Error: Invalid LatLng object: (22.648977723071596, undefined)
```

The way I am passing the JSON data

```
<AnyReactComponent lat={carLocation[.0]} lng={carLocation[.1]} />
```

JSON data:

```
"location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        22.65476963546529,
        88.4097751043737
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `lat={carLocation.coordinates[0]}` & `lat={carLocation.coordinates[1]}`.

```js
const carLocation = {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        22.65476963546529,
        88.4097751043737
      ]
    }

console.log("lat", carLocation.coordinates[0]);
console.log("lng", carLocation.coordinates[1]);
```